# Java Vs C# Long to DateTime Conversion

Tags: java, c#, datetime, date-conversion

In Java I have the following test that passes fine

```
// 42 bits of time is good enough for the next 100 years.
// An IEEE double has 52 bits of mantissa, so our dates can be easily fit.
@Test
public void testMaxBits() throws ParseException {
    // Maximum 42 bit integer
    long millis = (1L << 42) - 1;
    Date date = new Date(millis);
    //DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(2109, 5, 15, 8, 35, 11, 103);
    Date maxDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS").parse("2109-05-15T08:35:11.103");
    Assert.assertEquals(maxDate, date);
}
```

Now, I want to do the same sort of thing in C#, so I have a test in LinqPAD that test the C# implementation for correctness

```
DateTime maxDate = new DateTime(2109, 5, 15, 8, 35, 11, 103);
long beginTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc).Ticks;
long l = (1L << 42) - 1;
DateTime date = new DateTime(beginTicks + l, DateTimeKind.Utc);
maxDate.Dump();
date.Dump();
```

The output don't match, the values outputted `ToString()` values are

> maxDate = 15/05/2109 08:35:11
>   date    = 06/01/1970 02:10:04

What am I missing here?

---

*Edit. I have see a great answer below from @zmitrok, I have changed*

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(beginTicks + l, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

*to*

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(beginTicks + 
    l * TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond, DateTimeKind.Utc);
```

*but now get*

> date = 15/05/2109 07:35:11

*Where has the hour gone?*

Comment: Is `l` representing ticks?

Comment: Ticks != milliseconds. It's as simple as that. It's not clear what this is actually meant to be testing... 42 bits of milliseconds is enough for 100 years, but 42 bits of ticks isn't. Do you need accuracy down to the tick?

Comment: The existence of this test confuses me as it seems to be testing a component of the Date/DateTime API rather than something in the program itself.

Comment: Yeah, I am not attempting to test my code merely to ensure my translation to C# is correct, this test will not stay in my code base, in fact it was done in LinqPAD (without the [attributes] and `Asserts`). @JonSkeet I only need accuracy to the millisecond. I have ammended the question slightly, I now am seeing a minor

Comment: Your Java code is both overly-specific *and* a broken test. See my answer for details :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your test is basically confusing ticks with milliseconds. If you only need to store a number of milliseconds since the unix epoch, then do so - but I'd recommend using something like this to perform the conversion:

```
public static readonly DateTime UnixEpoch
    = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

public DateTime FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(long milliseconds)
{
     return UnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(milliseconds);
}
```

(As a side-note, [that method already exists](http://nodatime.org/1.3.x/api/html/M_NodaTime_Instant_FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch.htm) in my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project... hint hint :)

Your *test* would then be:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestMaxBits()
{
    long maxMillis = (1L << 42) - 1;
    DateTime maxDate = DateTimeHelper.FromMillisecondsSinceUnixEpoch(maxMillis);
    Assert.Greater(maxDate, new DateTime(2100, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0));
}
```

Note that:

- This code doesn't mention ticks at all, because you're not interested in ticks
- This code doesn't assert that the maximum date is some very specific value, because that's not what you care about; you care that 42 bits of time will carry you until the end of the century. (The "next 100 years" comment is somewhat specious, as 2109 is less than 100 years away from now, so I'll assume it really means "until the end of the 21st century.")

That of course make your question of "Where has the hour gone?" irrelevant - but the answer to that is simply that `SimpleDateFormat` defaults to using the system time zone, so you're actually relying on the time zone of the system you're running the test on, which is a *really* bad idea. If you set the time zone of the `SimpleDateFormat` to UTC, you'll find that it's 07:35:11 in Java as well.

Comment: Bang on, cheers for your help Jon, as always it is most appreciated. All the very best...

Answer (score 2):

The [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0d47c9c.aspx) you are using takes ticks as the first argument, however you are passing a value that was added to milliseconds.

> Ticks: A date and time expressed in the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since January 1, 0001 at 00:00:00.000 in the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to multiply ticks by this constant: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tickspermillisecond%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Or change the test more radically. It really depends on what the OP is doing with time elsewhere...